# If everyone in the world were a clone, would OPINIONS be considered OBJECTIVE?

Tags: meaning

**Simplified Core Issue of Question**: 
Do matters of opinion always fall under the umbrella of "*subjective*" by default?

**Original Question**: 
If everyone in the world were an identical clone, 
then would opinions be considered *objective*?

**Addendum**: 
(assume they share all thoughts + opinions about all subjects)
(assume this will not change)
(focus on the meaning of "*objective*", rather than the philosophy of the hypothetical)

**Rephrased**: does "*subjective*" still encompass opinions when an opinion is universal. 
(regarding when to use "*objective*" vs "*subjective*")

---

**Background**:
I ask this because I have always seen the word *subjective* used to mean the subject referenced "is a matter of opinion", or "up for debate".

But if there is no disagreement, never has been disagreement, and there will continue to be no disagreement, it's not "up for debate". I don't know how to incorporate this nuance into my present understanding of what "*subjective*" means.

Basically, can matters of opinion (*contrast with verifiable, or measurable matters of fact*) ever cross over to "*objective*"? or do they remain "*subjective*" even when you have a situation where **every** individual agrees.

---

**Example**:

> "Everyone agrees that causing pain, for its own sake, is morally bad."

In a (hypothetical) world where **everyone** has always, currently, and in the future will agree to something, do you still call this matter *subjective* or does it become *objective* when it is universally agreed upon?

---

---

> @ put on hold as unclear what you're asking:

I thought this was straightforward,
but I have clarified and added more information 
to explain

1. why I asked this (not in jest)
2. the nuance (/distinction) I was unsure about
3. an application that shows how this question is important

---

---

Comment: An opinion is not objective because it is universally held.

Comment: @TimRomano This is exactly what I'm wondering.

Comment: @sumelic Thank you. I have updated the question with a much more clear & precise wording (+ applicable context)

Comment: You don't think that identical twins ever have different opinions?

Comment: @HotLicks: Per the edits, this is not supposed to be a realistic scenario. It's an unrealistic "thought experiment" sort of thing.

Comment: An "opinion" is "subjective" if it depends on the judgment and/perception of the individual.  Since essentially everything that a human thinks is dependent on perception, one can argue that it's all "subjective".

Comment: (I'm guessing this question has been tossed around extensively by philosophers.  It's really a question of philosophy, not English.)

Comment: This should be the question in full: "In a hypothetical world where everyone has always, currently, and in the future will agree to something, do you still call this matter subjective or does it become objective when it is universally agreed upon?" - Neither; it's a *truth*.

Comment: @Mazura I really like this.

Comment: The main reason I ask this, is for use in philosophy. But I don't want to cherry-pick or redefine parts of the English language. I would like to write "It is objectively morally bad to cause pain, just for the sake of causing pain."

Comment: To discuss whether this moral idea is true or not, or to discern (or explore) the merit of an idea is philosophy. To discuss or clarify the meaning or use of the word is English.

Comment: again, focus less on the thought experiment. Try to focus on the meaning of **objective** and **subjective** ; as they are typically defined or used or understood -- "does opinion always fall under the umbrella of **subjective** ?"

Comment: You skipped my preferred meaning of *opinion*: "the beliefs or views of a **large number or majority of people** about a particular thing." –Google. Your example is therefore not an opinion, so it falls under neither. Can an opinion ever be objective? Now *that's* a philosophy question.

Comment: In case you're wondering, from a purely technical standpoint there can never be a human observation which is "objective" -- there is always a "subjective" component.  (And that's my objective opinion on the matter.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's so deep and philosophical and not simply about English language.

Comment: Have you checked [philosophy.se]? There are dozens of posts related to what you're asking.

Comment: @NVZ - I'd vote to close but I already voted to close once and some crazies voted it to be reopened, even though it's no more on topic than it was the first time.  The software won't let me close vote a second time.

Comment: I came here to begin with, hoping that subjective was always the same, even at extreme cases. But wanted to verify. See Silenus's answer for this clarification about English usage concerning  this.

Comment: @HotLicks It was closed the first time because the question was one sentence. As per my update "focus on the meaning of 'objective', rather than the philosophy of the hypothetical".

Comment: @HotLicks --- Trying to phrase what I was curious about (does the definition change at extremes?) was cumbersome, yes, but the NATURE of the question is exactly within the scope of English Language & Usage.

Comment: @HotLicks --- Again, the question was cumbersome, but the answer Silenus presented was simple and perfectly answers it (again, in regards to EL&U).

Comment: @HotLicks "and some crazies voted it to be reopened" ... please see ELU >> Help Center >> Our Model >> Be Nice. [http://english.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice ]

Comment: @PairSirParser You continue to miss the point that you're asking about philosophy, not English.  As a result, the question does not belong here.  EL&U is for questions about English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An opinion is still subjective if everyone has always, currently, and will always have it.

Consider the definitions of *subjective*:

> 1. existing in the mind; belonging to the thinking subject rather than to the object of thought
> 2. pertaining to or characteristic of an individual; personal; individual ([here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/subjective?s=t))

Now consider whether or not everyone having an opinion would make that opinion any less *mental*, or any less *characteristic of an individual*. It would not. It would still be mental and it would still be of an individual.

We can simplify your thought experiment to pump this intuition. Consider a world where there is only one individual and this individual has a single unchanging belief. His belief is that chocolate ice cream is tasty. In this scenario, we're still inclined to say that this belief is subjective, even though (by hypothesis) it's unchanging and shared by everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If everyone had the same opinions, those opinions could still be opined as subjective, but the state could not last long since the people would be subject to different experiences henceforth (since people are spatially distinct).